# Compare 3 columns from different data frame and putting the result in a separate column with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am new to python and I have come up with a issue where
I have 3 DF's like:

DF1:

```
|Transaction | Item         |Price  |Cost|
------------------------------------------
|    1       |milk          |20     |19  |
|    2       |milk;egg      |80     |70  |
|    3       |Sugar         |35     |32  |
|    4       |Battery;Salt  |30     |18  |
|    5       |Sauce         |90     |80  |
```

DF2:

```
 Category A
 milk
 Salt 
 sugar
```

DF3:

```
Category B
egg
battery
```

Expected outcome:

A new column in DF1 name category which shows the category of each product :

```
final
A
A;B
A
B;A
None
```

Please suggest how could i do this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! You should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :) (such as code samples, giving more context of what you are trying to achieve, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create flatten dictionary for keys by categories with match splitted values and if failed is created empty string, which is repalced in last step to `None`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['milk','milk;Sauce;egg','Sugar','Battery;salt', 'Souce']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Category A':['milk','sugar','salt']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Category B':['egg','battery']})

d1 = {'A':df2['Category A'],
     'B':df3['Category B']}

d = {x.lower(): k for k, v in d1.items() for x in v}

f = lambda x: ','.join(d.get(y.lower(), 'None') for y in x.split(';'))
df1['new'] = df1['Item'].apply(f)
df1['new'] = df1['new'].replace({'':None})

print (df1)
             Item       new
0            milk         A
1  milk;Sauce;egg  A,None,B
2           Sugar         A
3    Battery;salt       B,A
4           Souce      None
```

Comment: Your solution is wrong check the output in `row 3`.

Comment: Hi. thanks for the solution but when i try to run it following error is coming : AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: @jezrael I tried but the same error occurs. the error occur in line 2  for x where we are defining d . so i chaned it as

d = {str(x).lower(): k for k, v in d1.items() for x in v}

so that it will be read as a string but when i run the code it assign A to all the values.

Comment: @Ankit - understand, then need `{'A':df2['Category A'].dropna(),
     'B':df3['Category B'].dropna()}` for remove rows with missing values

Comment: @jezrael  Now its assigning B too but is not considering the values after ; in df1['Item']

Comment: @jezrael yes. Is possible be more specific what means  meaning look at row 2 milk;egg result is giving output for only milk and not considering egg

Comment: @jezrael yes I understand and solution is working fine with this sample data.

Comment: @Ankit - You need find rows which failed and analyze. Btw, e.g. whats is ouput if `milk;Sauce;egg` ?

Comment: @jezrael   in that case output is coming as a,b  required output will be a,none,b

Comment: also in case of battery;salt the answer is coming as none. even though the answer should be b,a

Comment: @Ankit - `battery,salt` return `None` (because separator is `,`), but `battery;salt` working perfectly, added to answer.

Comment: @Ankit - Answer was changed for `milk;Sauce;egg` to `a,none,b `

Comment: @jezrael yes now its producing correct result. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['milk','milk;egg','sugar','battery;salt','pepper','pepper;sugar']})
cata = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['milk','sugar','salt']})
catb = pd.DataFrame({'Item':['egg','battery']})
cata_list = cata.Item.values.tolist()
catb_list = catb.Item.values.tolist()

def get_category(x):
    items = x.split(";")
    cat = []
    for i in items:
        print(i)
        if i in cata_list:
            cat.append('a')
        elif i in catb_list:
            cat.append('b')
        else:
            cat.append('None')
    print(cat)
    return ",".join(i for i in cat) 

df['category'] = df['Item'].apply(get_category)
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution is working fine but it doesn't mention the case in which value is not in either category thus None should be written

Answer (score 0):

#### [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

We can create a replacement dictionary from the columns `Category A` and `Category B` then we can `replace` the matching strings in the `Item` column with the help of this replacement dictionary.

```
d = {**dict.fromkeys(df2['Category A'].radd(r'(?i)'), 'A'), 
     **dict.fromkeys(df3['Category B'].radd(r'(?i)'), 'B')}

df['final'] = df['Item'].replace(d, regex=True).mask(lambda x: x.eq(df['Item']))
```

---

```
   Transaction          Item  Price  Cost final
0            1          milk     20    19     A
1            2      milk;egg     80    70   A;B
2            3         Sugar     35    32     A
3            4  Battery;Salt     30    18   B;A
4            5         Sauce     90    80   NaN
```

Comment: hmmm, whats happen if `Battery;Souce;Salt` ?

Comment: @jezrael Well that depends on OP to tell. And logically if the replacement is not possible then it makes sense to just. replace the matching categories

Comment: ya, I solve this problem remove this category, in your solution stay not touch.

Comment: I'd like it that way to not remove even the matching ones.

Comment: below error is coming when i tried to run this. Can you suggest how to fix it ..
 missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 42.